# Wordpress Bootstrap css of Theme loads after Child Theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make my Child Theme Css load after the Parent Theme Css(s) is loaded.

Currently my page isn't displaying correctly because the Parent's bootstrap overrides my child-theme CSS. I cannot simply delete bootstrap from the parent, since any Theme update would include bootstrap again.
Here is my function.php in my Child Theme.
The Activello Theme comes with Bootstrap pre-included (assets/css/bootstrap.min.css)

Is there anything wrong in my PHP ?

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

 $parent_style = 'activello';
 wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
 wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/style.css', array( $parent_style ),
 wp_get_theme()->get('Version'));

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );`
```

Comment: Are you sure the child theme CSS isn't loading after the parent theme? (I'm guessing it absolutely does, given my understanding of WP).  I'm suspecting that the problem you are facing has to do with the CSS selector(s) not being the right [specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) to address the elements that have been already styled by the parent theme CSS.

Comment: When I started making the website, I was using the same Theme, "Activello" with bootstrap included and I had no child-theme. I was using a plugin called Simple Custom CSS, to be able to easily have my css in all of the themes...even after an update. It was working fine... but since the Child-Theme switch I made...I'm facing this issue, of bootstrap overriding my selectors. I could modify all the selectors..but my css file is quite big, and it was working fine before...

Comment: I'll try to change what bootstrap overrides.. since it's not affecting a lot of selectors. Thank you ! @cale_b